# Problems installing mysql on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, mysql

I hit the following error shortly on entering the mysql "root" password:

```
An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. 
This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a
communication problem with the MySQL server.
```

Here is the full output of apt-get install mysql-server:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl
  libsql-statement-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/8,797 kB of archives.
After this operation, 93.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:i386.
(Reading database ... 88930 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.109-4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:i386 (0.3.109-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:i386 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbi-perl_1.630-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.025-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-readkey-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-readkey-perl_2.31-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 89293 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libaio1:i386 (0.3.109-4) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:i386 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
141117 20:53:10 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To completely uninstall mysql, I have run through the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deluser mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

This seems to completely remove everything, but subsequent installation attempts produce the same problem.

I have also set permissions on /tmp.

It may be of note that Postgres is installed on this machine, but from what I understand this should not be a problem.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175820/mysql-doesnt-update-due-to-error-in-apparmor-profile/248860#248860

Comment: Thank you Tim, but this did not change the outcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key clue is probably this line in the output:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
```

1. Make sure MySQL is entirely removed/purged

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql /etc/mysql
   sudo deluser mysql

   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo reboot
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I tried to use MariaDB 10.0 with MySQL Workbench, and the were some issues, the point is that I end up installing and uninstalling MySQL and MariaDB packages until I broke all and I could not install either MariaDB or MySQL.I had a bad time trying to solve it and finally I found a solution, I made it from similar questions related with this issue and with dpkg and apt problems. This is the same for MariaDB or MySQL. So...here is the solution:

I did all the same as you:

```
sudo aptitude purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo aptitude autoclean
sudo deluser mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

And from now, I did this based on answers of dpkg issues. I don't know if this is the safest but well, it worked:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
sudo rm -rf mysql*
```

And that was all, I installed again and it worked. I hope this is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you have used the command

`sudo rm -rf /ver/lib/mysql` instead of `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`

Make sure my.cnf was removed from the location /etc/my.cnf.

```
sudo rm /etc/my.cnf

sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

Once it is done, try reinstalling mysql server again.

Comment: Excellent catch, but unfortunately the typo is in my question, not in the command I actually used.  I verified that these directories were cleared before proceeding with the reinstall.