# Can't install mysql-server on 14.04

Tags: server, mysql

Ubuntu Server 14.04, everything on the server is fully updated. No matter what I try, I cannot get `mysql-server` to install. I followed all answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550742/problems-installing-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04), and I even tried `sudo apt-get purge mysql.*`. Nothing works. What's going on?

Error I get:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
(Reading database ... 110435 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
chfn: PAM: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
adduser: `/usr/bin/chfn -f MySQL Server mysql' returned error code 1. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if at some point you created a regular user account with the username `mysql`, which is interfering with the creation of a `mysql` system user? What does `getent passwd mysql` say?

Comment: @steeldriver `mysql:x:106:114::/nonexistent:/bin/false` I did delete the user each time before I ran `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

It will list the packages belonging to the mysql.

```
Then try the following command 

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove mysql*
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After that

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql
```

After the above steps try installing mysql again.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the log you listed is:

> ```
> You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
> chfn: PAM: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
> adduser: `/usr/bin/chfn -f MySQL Server mysql' returned error code 1. Exiting.
> ```

It's a bit confusing because it's happening during installation of MySQL, but what this is trying to explain is that your `root` account for Ubuntu (not MySQL) needs to be changed. I was turned on to this by [a similar error in a bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/armbian/build/issues/224).

You can verify that this is the issue with `sudo chage -l root` (yes, `chage`). You'll see something like:

> ```
> Last password change                              : password must be changed
> Password expires                                  : password must be changed
> Password inactive                                 : password must be changed
> Account expires                                   : never
> Minimum number of days between password change    : 0
> Maximum number of days between password change    : 14600
> Number of days of warning before password expires : 14
> ```

You need to reset the root password with `chpasswd "root:YOURPASSWORD"`. (You can generate a random hex password with `$(openssl rand -hex 32)`.)

You should now see something like:

> ```
> Last password change                              : Oct 17, 2018
> Password expires                                  : never
> Password inactive                                 : never
> Account expires                                   : never
> Minimum number of days between password change    : 0
> Maximum number of days between password change    : 14600
> Number of days of warning before password expires : 14
> ```

**And you should be able to install MySQL successfully now!**

Answer (score 0):

After performing the above steps, please follow below steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install this in `noninteractive` mode, like in a `Dockerfile`, try this:

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client`